# Why is the docking bay locked?

Tags: subnautica

I was just trying to get to my seamoth when the docking bay said "locked" when I hovered over it. I then tried to go in from the side to investigate, but it was locked too. Why can't I access my seamoth (I put it in the Cyclops by the way)

Comment: On the 2nd floor, there are doors that lead under the seamoth/prawn

Comment: Screenshots would be helpful

Comment: not my screenshots but its the exact thing that's happening to me https://imgur.com/a/otHXG

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I encountered the same issue. The reason was that there was not enough space between my Cyclops and the ground. Just needed to elevate a little bit the Cyclops.